# How best to test controller variable assignment of has_many associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am trying and failing to test a controller for variable assignment of the belongs_to objects. These are controller tests and there are a number of areas I could really appreciate with some help on, namely

1. Should I be writing such tests here and in this way.
2. If so how could i get it working.

Code as below:

Company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to  :user
    has_many        :employees, inverse_of: :company
    has_many        :quotes, inverse_of: :company
end
```

Quote.rb

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company
end
```

Employee.rb

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company
end
```

Company has a controller with usual CRUDs, Quote has a controller with Show and Index,  Employee does not have a controller. Companies#create creates all three objects and `redirect_to`'s to Quotes#show which renders various attrs from all three models.

companies_controller.rb #create

```
def create
    @company = current_user.companies.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
      @quote = @company.quotes.last
      @employees = @company.employees.all
      redirect_to company_quote_url(@company, @quote, @employees), notice: 'Quote request created'
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

quotess_controller.rb #show

```
def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @quote = @company.quotes.find(params[:id])
    @employees = @company.employees.all
end
```

I have a Factory Girl factory set up for eahc of the models:

Companies.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    sequence(:co_name) { |n| "Acme Co #{n}" }
    co_number "06488522"
    postcode "al1 1aa"
    industry :financial_services

    factory :company2 do
    end

    factory :company3 do
    end
  end
end
```

Quotes.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :quote do
    lives_overseas true
    payment_frequency :monthly

    factory :quote2 do
    end

    factory :quote3 do
    end
  end
end
```

Employees.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :employee1, class: Employee do
    first_name "MyString"
    last_name "MyString"
    email "test@test.com"
    gender "MyString"
    date_of_birth "2000-06-20"
    salary 10000

    factory :employee2 do
    end

    factory :employee3 do
    end
  end
end
```

And I am trying to write controller tests for Quote#show and to test the assignment of the three objects, i.e.; `@company`, `@quote` & `@employees` to the relataive variables. Code so far as below:

quotes_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe QuotesController, type: :controller do
  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:company) { FactoryGirl.create(:company, user: user) }
  let(:employee1) { FactoryGirl.create(:employee1, company: company) }
  let(:employee2) { FactoryGirl.create(:employee2, company: company) }
  let(:employee3) { FactoryGirl.create(:employee3, company: company) }
  let(:quote) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote, company: company) }

  describe "GET #show" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :show, params: { company_id: company.id, id: quote.id, , employee_id: employee1.id }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "assigns requested quote to @quote" do
        get :show, params: { company_id: company.id, id: quote.id, employee1.id: employee1.id } #, employee_id: employee1.id
        expect(assigns(:quote)).to eq(quote) # passes fine
        expect(assigns(:company)).to eq(company) # passes fine
        expect(assigns(:employee1)).to eq(employee1) # fails 
    end
  end
end
```

I get an error as below:

Failures:

```
  1) QuotesController GET #show assigns requested quote to @quote
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:employee1)).to eq(employee1)

       expected: #<Employee id: 1, first_name: "MyString", last_name: "MyString", email: "test@test.com", gender: "m",...alary: 10000, company_id: 178, created_at: "2017-07-01 11:21:27", updated_at: "2017-07-01 11:21:27">
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/quotes_controller_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When i run the app and use `params.inspect` in Quote#show template after a Company#create these are the params that are passed:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"quotes", "action"=>"show", "company_id"=>"109", "id"=>"109", "format"=>"#<Employee::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fc2694a07f8>"} permitted: false>
```

I feel like there are a few core things I am not getting right here;

1. I need somehow to declare the associations within Factory Girl
2. My tests should somehow be testing the presence of a collection and its assignment to the `@employees` variable in `Quotes#show`, not assignment of just one employee record, which is what I'm trying, and failing, to do above.
3. I am unsure about whether I am crossing 'lines of separation' that perhaps ought to be present because I am testing on other model objects (Company, Quote and Employee) created in `Companies#create` and rendered in `Quotes#show`.

Any help and or guidance appreciated. The afternoon reading and googling leaves me still at a loss as to how I can get my testing strategy right here and the syntax correct for it to work properly. Incidentally all works in the app just fine, I'd just like to be able to test the assignment of the correct object in this Quotes#show method. Thanks.

Comment: The initial error looks like straightforward issue -- the **initial** field does not exist on the employee object, so that value cannot be set. My guess is that there is no corresponding field in your database.

Comment: Thanks @dbugger, silly mistake by me there, corrected, now on to a new failure relating to the employee factory object not being assigned to the variable. Answer updated above.

Comment: You assign `@employees` but test for `@employee1`. No wonder this check fails.

Comment: I see that @employees is defined in Quotes#show, so therefore I need to assign a number of employee factory objects to a collection (a hash with id as key and attrs in a hash as the value?) then i need to check that that same collection is assigned to @employees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to part 2 of this question, re. testing assignment of a collection, in the context of my code was either:

```
expect(assigns(:employees)).to include(employee1)
```

or

```
expect(assigns(:employees)).to eq([employee1])
```

Feedback on parts 1 and 3 of this question still sought.

Thanks